# in GeoPandas, select (line string) data within a latitude longitude box defined by user

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a geopandas dataframe consisting of a combination of LineStrings and MultiLineStrings.  I would like to select those LineStrings and MultiLineStrings containing a point within a box (defined by me) of latitude longitude, for which I don't have a geometry.  In other words, I have some mapped USGS fault traces and I would like to pick a square inset of those fault lines within a certain distance from some lat/lons.  So far I've had some success unwrapping just coordinates from the entire data frame and only saving points that fall within a box of lat/lon, but then I no longer keep the original geometry or information saved in the data frame.  (i.e. like this:)

```
xvals=[]
yvals=[]
for flt in qfaults['geometry']:
    for coord in flt.coords:
       if coord[1] >= centroid[1]-1 and coord[1] <= centroid[1]+1 and coord[0]<=centroid[0]+1 and coord[0]>=centroid[0]-1:
           xvals.append(coord[0])
           yvals.append(coord[1])
```

Is there any intuition as to how to do this using the GeoPandas data frame?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post sample data along with expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoPandas has `.cx` indexer which works exactly like this. See https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Syntax is `gdf.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]`

```py
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
southern_world = world.cx[:, :0]
western_world = world.cx[:0, :]
western_europe = world.cx[1:10, 40:60]
```